# How to insert a newline in list using regex in python 2.7?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, loops, newline

I am trying to make an ordered dataset out of an OCR scan. I have preprocessed the result by making a list which contains all 'units' - separated by newlines. 
This looks like this:

```
[' 525-11 Prof.Dr.F.J.A.Kreuzer, Nijmegen  onderzoek met betrekking tot de fysiologie van ademhaling en bloedsomloop op grote hoogte  17.500\n', 
' 527-7 Dr.G.Buyze, Utrecht  onderzoek naar het kopermetabolisme bij geesteszicken  s 9.400\n', 
' 527-8  Prof. Dr. Elisabeth P.Steyn Parv\xc3\xa9, Utrecht onderzoek naar de betekenis van thiaminc voor de synthese van vetzuren in het dierlijk lichaam  s 5.400\n', 
' 532-7 Dr.J.K. Sch\xc3\xb6nfeld, Rotterdam  onderzoek over de rol van de L-fase van bacteri\xc3\xabn bij chronische en recidiverende ziekten (1962)  f 3.100\n', 
' 532-8  A.G.Schuitemaker, Heiloo  onderzoek naar het lytisch vermogen van bacteriofagen voor mycobacteri\xc3\xabn f 2.000\n', 
' 542-13 Dr.B.Leijnse en Dr.H.M. van Praag, Rotterdam  bestudering van het werkingsmechanisme van de anti-depressieve hydrazinen, in bio chemisch en psychiatrisch-psychologisch opzicht  f 16.000\n', 
' 547-7 Dr.H.K.A. Visser, Groningen  onderzoek over de werking van het antidiuretische hormoon en de regulatie van de centrale afgifte van dit hormoon gedurende de kinderleeftijd (1962)  s 9.600\n', 
' 548-4 Dr.F.Schwarz, Utrecht  onderzoek naar de invloed van Exophthalmos Producing Substance op bindweefsel  s 13.000\n', 
' 562-8 Prof. Dr.J.Droogleever Fortuyn, Groningen  onderzoek naar bouw en functie van de middenhersenen (1960-1962) f 13.100\n', 
' '
]
```

I now want to insert newlines (`\n`) after all the patterns identified with this regular expression:

```
r" ([0-9]+[-][0-9])"
```

So the result should be, for example:

```
525-11
Prof.Dr.F.J.A.Kreuzer, Nijmegen  onderzoek met betrekking tot de fysiologie van ademhaling en bloedsomloop op grote hoogte  17.500

527-7 Dr.G.Buyze, Utrecht  onderzoek naar het kopermetabolisme bij geesteszicken  s 9.400

527-8  Prof. Dr. Elisabeth P.Steyn Parv, Utrecht onderzoek naar de betekenis van thiaminc voor de synthese van vetzuren in het dierlijk lichaam  s 5.400
```

I tried to make a loop in which all matching patterns are substituted with the same matching pattern + a new line. But this only seems to work one single time, so it looks like something goes wrong with the loop. Does anyone have an idea what specifically goes wrong?

```
    #import Regular Expression library
    import re

    #Open a the preprosseced text file
    g = open('outputtest2.txt', 'r')
    h = open('outputtest3.txt', 'w')
    SingularStringTextDOC = g.readlines()
    aanvr = re.compile(r" ([0-9]+[-][0-9])")

    #Test how the string works
    print(SingularStringTextDOC)

    #Make a Loop in which in every line in the text of outputtest1.txt is 
    searched for submission number
    for line in SingularStringTextDOC:
        if aanvr.match(line):
            AddLine = re.sub(r" ([0-9]+[-][0-9]+)", '\g<1>\n', line)

    #test result
    print(AddLine)

    #create a new file in which the new lines are added
    IsolatedSubmissionText_Aanvrnum = h.write(AddLine)
```

The result (including test prints):

```
[ ' 515-16  Prof. Dr.D.B.Kroon, Amsterdam onderzoek naar samenstelling en structuur van ooglens-ciwitten  f 16.900\n', 
" 521-21 Prof.Dr.E.C.Slater, Amsterdam  onderzoek over aard en werkingsmechanisme van de zogenaamde 'relaxing factor' (1960  1962)  f 12.000\n", 
' 525-11 Prof.Dr.F.J.A.Kreuzer, Nijmegen  onderzoek met betrekking tot de fysiologie van ademhaling en bloedsomloop op grote hoogte  17.500\n', 
' 527-7 Dr.G.Buyze, Utrecht  onderzoek naar het kopermetabolisme bij geesteszicken  s 9.400\n', 
' 527-8  Prof. Dr. Elisabeth P.Steyn Parv\xc3\xa9, Utrecht onderzoek naar de betekenis van thiaminc voor de synthese van vetzuren in het dierlijk lichaam  s 5.400\n', 
' 532-7 Dr.J.K. Sch\xc3\xb6nfeld, Rotterdam  onderzoek over de rol van de L-fase van bacteri\xc3\xabn bij chronische en recidiverende ziekten (1962)  f 3.100\n', 
' 532-8  A.G.Schuitemaker, Heiloo  onderzoek naar het lytisch vermogen van bacteriofagen voor mycobacteri\xc3\xabn f 2.000\n', 
' 542-13 Dr.B.Leijnse en Dr.H.M. van Praag, Rotterdam  bestudering van het werkingsmechanisme van de anti-depressieve hydrazinen, in bio chemisch en psychiatrisch-psychologisch opzicht  f 16.000\n', 
' 547-7 Dr.H.K.A. Visser, Groningen  onderzoek over de werking van het antidiuretische hormoon en de regulatie van de centrale afgifte van dit hormoon gedurende de kinderleeftijd (1962)  s 9.600\n', 
' 548-4 Dr.F.Schwarz, Utrecht  onderzoek naar de invloed van Exophthalmos Producing Substance op bindweefsel  s 13.000\n', 
' 562-8 Prof. Dr.J.Droogleever Fortuyn, Groningen  onderzoek naar bouw en functie van de middenhersenen (1960-1962) f 13.100\n', ' ']

562-8

Prof. Dr.J.Droogleever Fortuyn, Groningen  onderzoek naar bouw en functie van de middenhersenen (1960-1962) f 13.100
```

Comment: Try the `print(AddLine)`  right after `AddLine = re.sub(r" ([0-9]+[-][0-9]+)", '\g<1>\n', line)` on the same indented level instead of from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks! That's it: I understand now that I also have to write on the same indented level of the loop..

Comment: Do you also have any ideas on how I can insert a newline (\n) before another matching pattern?

Comment: Do you mean insert a newline before the capturing group? `\n\g<1>\n` https://regex101.com/r/mjDtDj/1

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you might simply want to add word boundaries to your expression, also a `+` seems to be missing:

```
\s\b[0-9]+-[0-9]+\b
```

not sure though.

#### Test

```
import re

l = [' 525-11 Prof.Dr.F.J.A.Kreuzer, Nijmegen  onderzoek met betrekking tot de fysiologie van ademhaling en bloedsomloop op grote hoogte  17.500\n', 
' 527-7 Dr.G.Buyze, Utrecht  onderzoek naar het kopermetabolisme bij geesteszicken  s 9.400\n', 
' 527-8  Prof. Dr. Elisabeth P.Steyn Parv\xc3\xa9, Utrecht onderzoek naar de betekenis van thiaminc voor de synthese van vetzuren in het dierlijk lichaam  s 5.400\n', 
' 532-7 Dr.J.K. Sch\xc3\xb6nfeld, Rotterdam  onderzoek over de rol van de L-fase van bacteri\xc3\xabn bij chronische en recidiverende ziekten (1962)  f 3.100\n', 
' 532-8  A.G.Schuitemaker, Heiloo  onderzoek naar het lytisch vermogen van bacteriofagen voor mycobacteri\xc3\xabn f 2.000\n', 
' 542-13 Dr.B.Leijnse en Dr.H.M. van Praag, Rotterdam  bestudering van het werkingsmechanisme van de anti-depressieve hydrazinen, in bio chemisch en psychiatrisch-psychologisch opzicht  f 16.000\n', 
' 547-7 Dr.H.K.A. Visser, Groningen  onderzoek over de werking van het antidiuretische hormoon en de regulatie van de centrale afgifte van dit hormoon gedurende de kinderleeftijd (1962)  s 9.600\n', 
' 548-4 Dr.F.Schwarz, Utrecht  onderzoek naar de invloed van Exophthalmos Producing Substance op bindweefsel  s 13.000\n', 
' 562-8 Prof. Dr.J.Droogleever Fortuyn, Groningen  onderzoek naar bouw en functie van de middenhersenen (1960-1962) f 13.100\n', 
' '
]

regex = r"(\s\b[0-9]+-[0-9]+\b)"
subst = "\\1\\n"


for index,item in enumerate(l):
    l[index] = re.sub(regex, subst, item)

print(l)
```

#### Output

> [' 525-11\n Prof.Dr.F.J.A.Kreuzer, Nijmegen  onderzoek met betrekking
>   tot de fysiologie van ademhaling en bloedsomloop op grote hoogte 
>   17.500\n', ' 527-7\n Dr.G.Buyze, Utrecht  onderzoek naar het kopermetabolisme bij geesteszicken  s 9.400\n', ' 527-8\n  Prof. Dr.
>   Elisabeth P.Steyn ParvÃ©, Utrecht onderzoek naar de betekenis van
>   thiaminc voor de synthese van vetzuren in het dierlijk lichaam  s
>   5.400\n', ' 532-7\n Dr.J.K. SchÃ¶nfeld, Rotterdam  onderzoek over de rol van de L-fase van bacteriÃ«n bij chronische en recidiverende
>   ziekten (1962)  f 3.100\n', ' 532-8\n  A.G.Schuitemaker, Heiloo 
>   onderzoek naar het lytisch vermogen van bacteriofagen voor
>   mycobacteriÃ«n f 2.000\n', ' 542-13\n Dr.B.Leijnse en Dr.H.M. van
>   Praag, Rotterdam  bestudering van het werkingsmechanisme van de
>   anti-depressieve hydrazinen, in bio chemisch en
>   psychiatrisch-psychologisch opzicht  f 16.000\n', ' 547-7\n Dr.H.K.A.
>   Visser, Groningen  onderzoek over de werking van het antidiuretische
>   hormoon en de regulatie van de centrale afgifte van dit hormoon
>   gedurende de kinderleeftijd (1962)  s 9.600\n', ' 548-4\n
>   Dr.F.Schwarz, Utrecht  onderzoek naar de invloed van Exophthalmos
>   Producing Substance op bindweefsel  s 13.000\n', ' 562-8\n Prof.
>   Dr.J.Droogleever Fortuyn, Groningen  onderzoek naar bouw en functie
>   van de middenhersenen (1960-1962) f 13.100\n', ' ']

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Ps26PH/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Ps26PH/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: That does not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks Emma, in this way, I have to change my method. But it does the trick as well!

Comment: For the example data it does not really matter if there is a `+` missing in the first pattern because it is a mere check done by `re.match` which will succeed as nothing follows the digits in both patterns. The sub on the next does contain the second `+`. Why match a word boundary `\b` after `\s`? The second `\b` does not make a difference because in the example data the numbers are followed by a space. Note that the OP uses a space and `\s` also matches a newline which may give unexpected results. Why use a capturing group instead of `\s\b[0-9]+-[0-9]+\b` and replace with `r"\g<0>\n"`?

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of AddLine you have to use `print(AddLine)` at the same indenting level right under `AddLine = re.sub(r" ([0-9]+[-][0-9]+)", '\g<1>\n', line)`

If you want the capturing group to start at a new line, you could prepend `\n` to the capturing group:

```
\n\g<1>\n
```

Note that in the pattern, you could also match the hyphen without the character class:

`([0-9]+-[0-9]+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S5NiXl/1)